# Excel how to true and false with 2 conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In excel I've 2 columns A and B with these datas :

```
ID  Group
999 32
502 32
075 32
233 32
999 36
233 36
752 36
```

I would like to know if the couple of data I put in the column D and E exists:

```
Groupe  36
ID  752
```

I wrote this formula I inserted in the cell F2 expecting 0 or 1 (false and true will be better)

```
=INDEX(E1:E2;MATCH(1;INDEX((E1=B2:B8)*(E2=A2:A8);0);0))
```

I've got a name Error in error in Excel

I was inspired by this page : https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8=E2)*(B2:B8=E1))>0
```

[image]

Or

COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,E1)>0
```

You may need to change the `,` to `;` depending on your local settings.

[image]